# How to increment an index for each card in a listview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I begin with Flutter and I work on it with a firestore database, I have a listview which display one card by document of my collection but I'm stuck on the delete button for them. I wanted to put it into the same card and work with an index on which I add +1 to delete the document but I can't do it.

I don't know if I use the good way, I link to this post the part code concerning the cards and a screen capture.

[Screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erGY3.png)

```
class _ArticleDataState extends State<ArticleData> {
  final index = 0;
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Article').snapshots();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return Card(
            final index = index + 1,
            elevation: 3.0,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
              child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface),
              child: ListTile(
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                  title: Text(
                   data['name'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Wrap(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(data["text"],
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary))
                    ],
                  ),
                  trailing: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidTrashCan,
                      color: Colors.blue, size: 25.0), onPressed: () {
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Article").doc(snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference.id.toString()).delete().then(
                          (doc) => showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => _buildPopupDialog(context),
                          )
                    );
                  },
            ),
            ),
          ));
        },
          ).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: dont use final for index, just use index++

Comment: i need to keep the first final index = 0; and the final index = index + 1, need to become index++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ListView, use ListView.builder which takes care of indeces.

> The standard ListView constructor works well for small lists. To work
> with lists that contain a large number of items, it’s best to use the
> ListView.builder constructor.
>
> In contrast to the default ListView constructor, which requires
> creating all items at once, the ListView.builder() constructor creates
> items as they’re scrolled onto the screen.
> [reference](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists)

so change where you return listView to something like this:

```
 return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 3.0,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration:
            BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface),
        child: ListTile(
          contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
          title: Text(
            data['name'],
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          subtitle: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(data["text"],
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary))
            ],
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidTrashCan,
                color: Colors.blue, size: 25.0),
            onPressed: () {
              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("Article")
                  .doc(snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference.id.toString())
                  .delete()
                  .then((doc) => showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                            _buildPopupDialog(context),
                      ));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```